# Get every location update from GPS

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, location

I am new to iOS.
I am making one app using GPS location update.
I am fetching current location and update location to server.
I want to get every change in meter and update it to server.
Here is the code i am using:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init] ;
 locationManager.delegate = self; // send loc updates to myself
 locationManager.distanceFilter = 1.0f; // whenever we move
 locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
 [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

But the location is not updating after every meter. It updates but not regularly.

Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work like that. AGPS, which is what iPhone uses, has limited accuracy which depends on many factors. It uses GPS, Wi-Fi and Cell Towers triangulation and at any given moment it can use any combination of these. So, when GPS signal is lost and there is no Wi-Fi hotspots around you could be getting location based on Cell Towers location which is very inaccurate (a few hundred meters). It could be worse than that, you could be getting cached location which is nowhere near your current location. And even when you have GPS signal you can't expect to get 1 meter accurate location everywhere you go. GPS accuracy itself depends on many factors.

Comment: If i have good wi-fi than after coving how much distance i can expect a new location co -ordinate?

Answer (score 0):

Use kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation always. There is no real battery usage difference between that and kCLLocationAccuracyBest, they both use the GPS at top speed. The main difference is in the post-processing that Apple does.So you can try the kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation.